# Association not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, associations

I'm making a simple association between 2 models, Author and Story.

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :category_id, presence: {message: "Se debe escoger una categoría"}
    validates :cuento, presence: {message: "Debe tener algun relato para ingresar"}
    validates :nombre, presence: {message: "No se puede ingresar relato sin titulo"}

belongs_to :author, class_name: "Author", :primary_key=>"id", :foreign_key => "author_id"
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stories, :class_name => "Story", :primary_key => "id", :foreign_key =>"author_id"


end
```

And in the schema:

```
  create_table "authors", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.date     "bod"
    t.string   "pais"
    t.string   "ciudad"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

 create_table "stories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.date     "fecha"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "resumen"
    t.text     "cuento"
    t.integer  "author_id"
  end

  add_index "stories", ["author_id"], name: "index_stories_on_author_id", using: :btree
```

Now, if I do a simple query on the console, like:

Author.joins(:stories)

And this returns:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'stories' was not
>   found on Author; perhaps you misspelled it?

What can be causing problems with this query?

**UPDATE:** 
I added the suggestion:

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stories, class_name: "Story"
end
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author, class_name: "Author"
end
But, in the console looks the same error :(

'ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'stories' was not found on Author; perhaps you misspelled it?'
Some other ideas???' Thanks!

**UPDATE 2**
I make a change in the model code adding the suggestion of put the optionals class_name, foreign_key, primary_key, and still nothing ...

Comment: does `:authors` table have an `:id` column? looks like you have `:user_id` in there as well, is `:user_id` a foreign_key or primary_key for `:authors` table?

Comment: :user_id is related to another element of my model. Authors have the id field, and also :author_id is index, according with the  add_index "stories", ["author_id"], name: "index_stories_on_author_id", using: :btree

Comment: it looks right to me, maybe try writing out the full association? include `:class_name`, `:foreign_key`, and `:primary_key`

Answer (score 0):

This is strange as everything looks to be right. This is just a wild guess, but try adding class_name to the association i.e. `has_many :stories, class_name: "Story"`

Comment: I wondered if it perhaps had something to do with the inflector in another language not handling English plurals.

Comment: I'm very confused with this... i can do the join with a string joins("inner join ....") but the idea is to use the native way

Answer (score 0):

If you are inheriting your classes with `ActiveRecord::Base`
Then there is no need to give the extra options like: `:class_name => "Story", :primary_key => "id", :foreign_key =>"author_id"`

```
    class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :category_id, presence: {message: "Se debe escoger una categoría"}
      validates :cuento, presence: {message: "Debe tener algun relato para ingresar"}
      validates :nombre, presence: {message: "No se puede ingresar relato sin titulo"}

      belongs_to :author
    end

    class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :stories
    end
```

Just simplify the code as above. It would work.
Thanks.